# Show something is quasi-isomorphism by showing pullback is quasi-isomorphism.

Tags: homological-algebra, topos-theory, algebraic-stacks

My question is the following:

Let $T$ be a topos and $X\to e$ be a covering of the final object $e\in T$ with respect to the canonical topology.
We have a morphism of topoi $f\colon T/X\to T$ where $f^\star F=F\times X$ for $f\in T$.
Now Martin Olsson claims in *Algebraic Spaces and Stacks* in Lemma 2.4.18 that to check that a given morphism of complexes of Sheaf of modules in $T$ is quasi-isomorphism, it suffices to show that it becomes a quasi-isomorphism after pulling back to $T/X$.

Could anyone tell me what he means by that and why it is true?
Many thanks in advance.